# Given a unit vector $x\in\mathbb R^d$, what is the worst possible within-cluster sum of squares for 2-means clustering?

Tags: algorithms, lower-bounds, cluster-analysis

This is a question I [originally posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4062458/given-a-unit-vector-x-in-mathbb-rd-what-is-the-worst-possible-within-cluster) to math.stackexchange.com but it didn't attract any answers, and I was wondering if someone here can help.

---

Consider a unit vector $x\in\mathbb R^d$ ($\|x\|_2=1$), and a [$k$-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) of it for $k=2$.

How big can the within-cluster sum of squares get?

Formally:

> **How to upper bound**
> $$
> \max_{\|x\| = 1}\min_{\mu_1,\mu_2\in\mathbb R} \left(\sum_{i=1}^d\min\left\{\left(x_i-\mu_1\right)^2,\left(x_i-\mu_2\right)^2\right\}\right)\quad ?
> $$

---

A trivial bound is $1$, but I suspect a much tighter bound exists.

---

It's easy to show that this quantity is at least $1/4$, by considering $x$ for which third of its coordinates are proportional to $1$, third to $-1$, and third are zeros (e.g., $x=(1/\sqrt 2, -1/\sqrt 2, 0)$ if $d=3$).